# Trying to convert from long to wide format but ending up with every combination of variable

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to go from this structure:

```
game_id team pts
1 400597848 TOWS  53
2 400597848 COFC  50
3 400595519  ILL  49
4 400595519  WIS  68
```

To this:

```
game_id team1 pts1 team2 pts2
1 400597848 TOWS  53  COFC  50
3 400595519  ILL  49  WIS  68
```

Here's sample data:

```
d <- structure(list(game_id = c(400597848L, 400597848L, 400595519L,
400595519L), team = c("TOWS", "COFC", "ILL", "WIS"), pts = c(53L,
50L, 49L, 68L)), .Names = c("game_id", "team", "pts"), row.names = c(NA,
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried using `tidyr` and followed this tutorial: 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

However, when I try:

```
 spread(d, team, pts)
```

I get repeated columns for all teams but don't want all combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. data.table**

We could use `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`, which can take multiple 'value.var' columns.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'  (`setDT(d)`), create a sequence column ('ind'), grouped by 'game_id', and then use `dcast` on the modified dataset specifying the 'value.var' as 'team', and 'pts'.

```
dcast(setDT(d)[, ind:= 1:.N, by=game_id], game_id~ind, 
                   value.var=c('team', 'pts'))
#     game_id 1_team 2_team 1_pts 2_pts
#1: 400595519    ILL    WIS    49    68
#2: 400597848   TOWS   COFC    53    50
```

**2. base R**

Another option is using `reshape` from `base R` after creating the 'ind' column.

```
 d1 <- transform(d, ind=ave(seq_along(game_id), game_id, FUN=seq_along))

 reshape(d1, idvar='game_id', timevar='ind', direction='wide')
 #    game_id team.1 pts.1 team.2 pts.2
 #1 400597848   TOWS    53   COFC    50
 #3 400595519    ILL    49    WIS    68
```

Comment: @tcash21 No problem.  I think `spread` (at present) can take only single value columns (haven't checked the new vignettes).